# How to add a new json object to array which elements will be rendered as components on a page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change a state of an array which will have values derived from data.js file as a starting point. Changing a state means running function setAllThingsArray and adding new element which will be set using a function setThingsArray based on previous state (thingsArray). Do I need to map allThingsArray to get updated array with added elements and to list them ?

```
import React from "react";
import data from "../data";
import Stamp from "../components/Stamp";

export default function AddItem(props) {
  
  const [thingsArray, setThingsArray] = React.useState({
    key: 9,
    img: "../images/stamp1.jpg",
    name: "Stamp 5",
    description: "AAAA",
    rating: 78.0,
  });

  function addItem() {
    setAllThingsArray((prevAllThingsArray) => ({
      arr: [
        ...prevAllThingsArray.arr,
        setThingsArray((prevThingsArray) => ({
          ...prevThingsArray,
          key: prevThingsArray.key + 1,
          img: "../images/stamp1.jpg",
          name: "Stamp 5",
          description: "AAAA",
          rating: 78.0,
        })),
      ],
    }));
  }

  const [allThingsArray, setAllThingsArray] = React.useState(data);

  const allThingsElements = allThingsArray.map((st) => {
    return <Stamp key={st.key} st={st} />;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div className="form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Image" className="form--input" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Stamp title" className="form--input" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Description" className="form--input" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Rating" className="form--input" />
        {/* <button className="form--button" onClick={addStampToJson(json_stamp)}>
          Add Stamp
        </button> */}
        <button className="form--button" onClick={addItem}>
          Add Stamp
        </button>
      </div>
      <section className="stamps-list">{allThingsElements}</section>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is it correct to place setThingsArray function inside setAllThingsArray function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

state setters (`setAllThingsArray` and `setThingsArray`) are asynchronous, so you cannot use a state update within another state update. `setThingsArray` itself is also a function (not a state value), so you cannot set it directly into `setAllThingsArray` either.

I'd propose that you should add another variable to keep an updated object (not an updated state), and then update states separately with the updated object.

```
function addItem() {
    //add an updated object
    const updatedThingsArray = {
        ...thingsArray, //this is an actual previous state
        key: prevThingsArray.key + 1,
        img: "../images/stamp1.jpg",
        name: "Stamp 5",
        description: "AAAA",
        rating: 78.0,
    }
    setAllThingsArray((prevAllThingsArray) => ([
        ...prevAllThingsArray,
        updatedThingsArray, //it's become a new object with your updated data
      ]));

    setThingsArray(updatedThingsArray) //update it back to the `thingsArray` as the new state
  }
```

Comment: what about map function? The error in console says that allThingsArray.map is not a function? After I changed the code as you told me.

Comment: ah you set `allThingsArray.arr` instead of `allThingsArray`. That was modified by your above logic but I didn't notice. I just modified my answer for your fit, @code_rushh